# Is it possible to make PHPickerViewController display multiple selection ordering number, instead of just an tick icon?

Tags: ios, swift, photokit

Currently, if we perform multiple selection on `PHPickerViewController`, a tick icon is being used to indicate selection.

[image]

However, such information doesn't convey information for the selection ordering.

Is it every possible, to display the ordering number? This is an example from 3rd party library - https://github.com/mikaoj/BSImagePicker

As you can see, the 3rd party library is using 1,2,3... to convey selection ordering information

[image]

Can we achieve the same behavior in `PHPickerViewController`? We prefer to use `PHPickerViewController`, because it doesn't need to request permission to access photo library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such feature is supported in iOS15 beta. Here's the respond from Apple engineer.

> Check out the new selection configuration option in the iOS 15 (beta)
> SDK:
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phpickerconfiguration/3752714-selection
>
> Aside from setting a selection limit in the configuration, you can set
> the selection behavior to ordered to number the selected assets.

Answer (score 0):

There's no public API to achieve this using `PHPickerViewController`.

You may try to achieve this by hacking into view hierarchy of `PHPickerViewController`, however doing so is highly discouraged and you will most likely get a rejection from App Store.

[From the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phpickerviewcontroller) :

> **Important**
>
> You can’t subclass `PHPickerViewController` because its view hierarchy is private and not accessible through the public API.

You need to implement your own custom solution OR use a 3rd party library to do this.